AWS SCIM error message regex
This error appears in a log file (lightly formatted for easier reading):
StatusCode: 400 : Bad Request : {
  schema :[ urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error ]
  schemas :[ urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error ]
  detail : 1 validation error detected:
  Value at 'phoneNumbers.1.value' failed to satisfy constraint:
  Member must satisfy regular expression pattern:
  [\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{S}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\t\\n\\r  　]+
}

It's likely this is due to a phone number in this format:
+1 (212) 555-1212

Instead of one of these formats:
12125551212
+1.212.555.1212

How does one interpret this regex to confirm that?
